# How to remove a column when two columns have the same name in the same table using SQL in Databricks?

Tags: sql, databricks

For the example below, how do I remove/rename/delete one of the "Customer_ID" columns? (I have two columns of the same name after a join)?
I have tried the command `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;` and `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name new_column_name datatype(value);`.

| Customer_ID | Customer_ID | Country | Name | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00015803hkl | 00015803hkl | India | Ram | iPhone |

Comment: Best way: Start over and re-write your other join query and select only one of the customer_id columns rather than both. As far as altering current tables, that may be problematic if they are delta lake tables. What happens with your current attempt above?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a dataframe with duplicated columns after join, but it is not possible to have such physical table or a view. So you don't have anything to run your `ALTER TABLE` on.

Having a dataframe both using SQL and Dataframe API you can refer to specific column using table/view/subquery alias, eg.

```
> val df = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as foo) a
                           CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 as foo) b""")
> df.show

+---+---+
|foo|foo|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+

> df.select($"foo").show

AnalysisException: Reference 'foo' is ambiguous, could be: a.foo, b.foo.

> df.select($"b.foo").show

+---+
|foo|
+---+
|  2|
+---+

> val a = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as foo")
> val b = spark.sql("SELECT 2 as foo")
> a.join(b).select(a.col("foo")).show

+---+
|foo|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```